# How well does Mountain Bike body armor work?

Tags: mountain-bike, protection

I have started getting into mountain biking, i have already got knee and elbow pads and am considering getting some back/spine protection. I would describe my riding as trail/enduro so i do a fair amount of pedaling to the top then jumps and chutes down.

How well does body armor (especially back and breast plates) work and what features should I look for when buying them?

Comment: Voting to close: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: Go to a local shop (or shops) and see what they have.

Comment: Most of the guys I ride with wear limited body Armour if riding any uphill and reserve spine/neck protection and full face helmets for Lift or shuttle serviced trails, however, most are over 40, been riding for 20+years  and have had the fear center of brain appropriately calibrated to their skill set. My motto - "It does not need to be ride-able, as long as its dis-mountable"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Body armor works fairly well at preventing abrasions and cuts, but does not do as well against impact damage.  I wore a SixSixOne pressure suit for many years when downhilling.  Basically during all the slow and medium speed crashes it keeps you from walking away bleeding from rocks, bark and maybe small punctures (from exposed tree branches and such) depending on where they land.  It doesn't keep you from getting bruised (that much), and will do little to mitigate the forces you encounter during a high speed crash.  I still managed to dislocate my collar bone during a high speed crash in full armor.  However, I wasn't bleeding where my shoulder slammed into the tree, so there is that.  I'd sum up by saying body armor is NOT like a helmet for your body.  It will not protect your spine from a high impact crash, but it may keep the skin on your back from getting torn up.

As far as what to look for, I recommend the same things you's look for in any cycling gear.  It should fit well and be well made.  Depending on your riding conditions and weather, ventilation can be very important.  Even at 75F, my armor made me sweat like the dickens.  At 85F or 90F, I don't think I could have stood the heat, but I was used to riding in sub arctic (interior Alaska) conditions.